# jquery form $("form").submit() works but it does not work with given form id

Tags: jquery

It took me a while to extract this simple code from my huge form, please take a look at it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form #formcontact").submit(function(){
            alert('a');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<div>
    <form id="formcontact" action="" method="POST">
       <input id="contact_submit" type="submit" value="sub" />
    </form>
</div>
```

This does not work but if I replace `$("form #formcontact")` with `$("form")` it works, but I don't want it to be on every form.

Why is that? So strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$("form #formcontact") selects a child element of `<form>`. Remove the space and it will work:

```
$("form#formcontact")
```

or

```
$("#formcontact")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is wrong it should be `$("form#formcontact")` without the space, or just `$("#formcontact")` since ids should be unique.